# RxJava2 - Emitting items using PublishSubject

Tags: android, rx-java2, subject

I've a scenerio where I've

`subject1: PublishSubject` and `subject2:BehaviorSubject`.

First, I emit single item for `subject1`, then I emit item for `subject2`, but right after that I also want to emit different item to `subject1`.

```
fun emittingItems() {
    subject1.onNext(functionA1)
    subject2.onNext(functionB)
    if (something) subject1.onNext(functionA2)
}
```

What happens is, that I receive an item in this sequence: `functionA1`, `functionA2`, `functionB`.

Why do I get this behavior? How can I emit items in this sequence: `functionA1`, `functionB`,`functionA2`.

Subscribing to subjects:

```
val disposable = viewModel.subject1
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this::someFunction())
disposables.add(disposable)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` you schedule the propagation of events on the main thread. The scheduling itself is sequential, while each scheduled `Runnable` might handle more than one element added to the queue used for it.

It's a kind of race condition which will arise for sure when calling `emittingItems()` on the main thread itself and could arise when calling it from any other thread.

But since you're handling two different asynchronous streams, you cannot expect any sequential observation within the two different observers.

You can achieve the given, by merging both sources as one stream:

```
Observable.merge(subject1, subject2)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(subject);
```

Comment: With `merge` won't I get this sequence: `functionA1`, `functionA2`, `functionB`?

Comment: No, not with your setup. The merged observable will emit next events as these are emitted by the subjects.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, if I would do `subject1.onNext(A), subject1.onNext(B), subject1.onNext(C)` I would receive `A,B,C`, as it's same subject, right?

Comment: It depends. Like above, yes. In general you will receive events with observers, depending on the stream you set up. It's usually unrelated to the sources.